# ReactJS - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Why do I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
#{this.props.item.url}
```

nav-item.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

class NavItem extends React.Component
{
    render() {
        if (this.props.item.code == 'contact') {
            return <li><a href={'#' + this.props.item.url} className="button-open-overlay" data-target-id="{this.props.item.url}">{this.props.item.title}</a></li>
        } else {
            return <li><a href={this.props.item.url}>{this.props.item.title}</a></li>
        }
    }
}

export { NavItem as default }
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

push-nav.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

import NavItem from './nav-item';

class PushNav extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navitems: [],
        };
    }

    // Then fetch the data using $.get():
    componentDidMount() {
        this.serverRequest = $.getJSON(this.props.source, function (result) {
            this.setState({
                navitems: result.nav
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
    }

    render() {
        var loop = this.state.navitems.map(function(item, index){
            return <NavItem key={index} item={item}></NavItem>;
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <a className="visible-xs button-push-menu" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas="body">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
                </a>

                <div className="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas-sm offcanvas-md offcanvas-lg">
                    <ul className="push-nav">{ loop }</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export { PushNav as default }
```

Example data:

```
{
    "nav": [{
        "navId": "3",
        "title": "Art",
        "code": "art",
        "href": null,
        "style": null,
        "sort": "3",
        "url": "blog",
        "parentId": null,
        "totalChildren": "0",
        "createdOn": null,
        "updatedOn": null
    }, {
        "navId": "4",
        "title": "Technology",
        "code": "technology",
        "href": null,
        "style": null,
        "sort": "4",
        "url": "projects",
        "parentId": null,
        "totalChildren": "0",
        "createdOn": null,
        "updatedOn": null
    }, {
        "navId": "5",
        "title": "Contact",
        "code": "contact",
        "href": null,
        "style": null,
        "sort": "5",
        "url": "contact",
        "parentId": null,
        "totalChildren": "0",
        "createdOn": null,
        "updatedOn": null
    }]
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't produce the error you've described (I just tried it). Please put a **runnable** [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets, which support React and JSX (tick the second checkbox on the left-hand side to get JSX support).

Comment: There *is* a problem, though: `data-target-id="{this.props.item.url}"` is probably not what you meant (lose the `"`). But it doesn't cause the error you listed (it just sets `data-target-id` to the literal string `{this.props.item.url}` rather than filling it in with the result of that expression).

Comment: Indeed, please provide an example. I don't see the error either.

Comment: the code works fine, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/61510/)

Comment: thanks guys. found the error - `data-target-id="{this.props.item.url}"`

Answer (score 1):

This is because your data is being set on state on **componentDidMount** which is executed after initial rendering. So either set your data in **componentWillMount** or do following in NavItem component

```
import React from 'react';

class NavItem extends React.Component
{
    render() {
        if (this.props.item === undefined) {
          return null
       } else if (this.props.item.code == 'contact') {
            return <li><a href={'#' + this.props.item.url} className="button-open-overlay" data-target-id="{this.props.item.url}">{this.props.item.title}</a></li>
       } else {
            return <li><a href={this.props.item.url}>{this.props.item.title}</a></li>
       }
    }
}

export { NavItem as default }
```